# DatePicker setMinDate and setMaxDate

Tags: java, android, datepicker, calendar

Why is it that in my phone (Android 5.0.1) that the result is like this? The blue border marking that the date is selected is always 1 week early than the date selected? But in my emulator 4.4.2 it there is no such a problem.

This is what i did to set the min and max date:

```
Calendar minCal = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentYear = mDatePicker.getYear();
int currentMonth = mDatePicker.getMonth();
int currentDayOfMonth =  mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();
minCal.set(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDayOfMonth, 0, 0, 0);
Calendar maxCal = (Calendar) minCal.clone();
maxCal.set(currentYear, currentMonth+2, currentDayOfMonth, 0, 0, 0);
mDatePicker.setMinDate(minCal.getTimeInMillis());
mDatePicker.setMaxDate(maxCal.getTimeInMillis());
mDatePicker.updateDate(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDayOfMonth);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the value of

          mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();   

? Could it be that you don't need dayOfMonth but dayOfWeek?

Comment: @AntCopp dayOfMonth() is 15. There is no such thing as dayOfWeek(). Also this happens on my phone (Android 5.0.1) but not on my emulator (Android 4.4.2), so there is no issue with the logic. Is shld be some compatibility problem. Probably got another way to deal with it for higher version of Android